# Truecrypt Full Disk Encryption - Bootloader on USB stick/pendrive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, encryption, truecrypt, bootloader, disk-encryption

I thought about way to hide that I'm using truecrypt on HDD, other than truecrypt built-in decoy-OS feature - it has lots of disadvantages.

My idea is simple:
Use full disk encryption on my system drive( which i want to hide), while creating it make rescue disk on usb stick.
As can be read on Truecrypt site I can boot from rescue disk without copying bootloader to hard drive.

Then i will erase whole TC bootloader from HDD. I hope such disk under investigation will look like completly unformatted disk.

On second drive i will install unencrypted decoy OS.

Finnaly i will set boot sequence to USB->second drive.

When usb is present it will boot TC bootloader, than booting my hidden partition. Otherwise it will boot from second drive.

It will work as i expect it to? It is even possible? Some hints, pitfails ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer on TC forums.

Even with instuction how to do this:

http://forums.truecrypt.org/viewtopic.php?p=103025#103025

Answer (score 0):

You must have something significant to hide to go to these lengths!

In fact, this really isn't going to help if you come up against professionals with suitable forensic tools. A cursory examination of the PC will reveal 2 obvious facts. Firstly that the "clean" drive doesn't get used and files are not being updated in expected patterns. Secondly, the hidden partition is easily picked out with forensic tools and is easily detected as encrypted.

Better would be to have an innocuous truecrypt file containing any secret data with TC on a USB stick. Make sure that the TC executable looks innocuous as well though since if you are interviewed, the stick will certainly be taken and examined.

The truth is that if you come under suspicion and your PC examined closely, experts will always be able to tell that you have *something* hidden even if they cant see what it is.

Your complex idea will only get in your way and would only be missed by the most cursory examination - though it might get you through TSA checks at US airports! More likely though, they would simply get suspicious and confiscate the PC.